# NetoworkX set edge widths according to weights

Tags: python, numpy, graph, plotly, networkx

I have a numpy array:

```
[[12,  1,  5,  2,  2,  2,  1,  3,  1,  2],
   [ 1, 10,  3,  2,  1,  7,  2,  6,  1,  0],
   [ 5,  3, 26,  5,  1,  5,  2, 11,  3,  5],
   [ 2,  2,  5, 11,  1,  2,  1,  7,  2,  4],
   [ 2,  1,  1,  1, 17,  2,  1,  6,  2,  2],
   [ 2,  7,  5,  2,  2, 22, 12,  8,  1,  0],
   [ 1,  2,  2,  1,  1, 12, 21,  7,  0,  1],
   [ 3,  6, 11,  7,  6,  8,  7, 23,  0,  5],
   [ 1,  1,  3,  2,  2,  1,  0,  0,  3,  1],
   [ 2,  0,  5,  4,  2,  0,  1,  5,  1,  4]]
```

I am trying to create a 2D network graph such as [this](https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-network-graph/) - at the bottom of the page (just 2D).
I found a library called `networkx` that has a pretty simple function to create a 2D graph from a numpy array:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(array)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=1)
```

[image]
But it's not interactive.
I'm also trying to replace the labels on the graph with the actual labels of the array (which are strings- say, 'one', 'two'... 'ten').
Lastly, the goal is for the graph to have edges where the width of the edge is the number in the array.

Comment: The numpy array you supplied has two dimensions. How do you expect to produce a 3D graph without the third dimension? The website example defines x, y and z i.e. three dimensions...

Comment: That is a very good point that I have not thought about. I'll start with 2D and go from there. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through [`nx.draw`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html) you can customise the visualisation to fit most of the mentioned requirements. Though in some cases you might need to use other options available in [Drawing](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/drawing.html) such as [`nx. draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes) etc. for further customisation.

In this case, and assuming you have an arraylike with the label names you want to set, you can use [`nx.draw_networkx_labels`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html) and specify the mapping of the labels with a dictionary, which you could define as:

```
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(a)

nodelist = G.nodes()
num_words = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']
d_labels = dict(zip(nodelist, num_words))
```

Note that by using `nx.from_numpy_matrix` the actual values in the array are set as edge `weights`, so you can use `nx.get_edge_attributes` to obtain the corresponding edge widths.

```
widths = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
```

The widths can be later set in [`nx.draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html) through the `width` parameter. Finally, in regards to making the graph interactive, you may look into [`node_picking`](https://networkx.github.io/grave/latest/gallery/node_picking.html).

Putting it all together, we can plot the graph as:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18,13))

pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=0.2)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=nodelist,
                       with_labels=True,
                       node_size=1500,
                       node_color='black',
                       font_color='white',
                       alpha=0.7)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,
                       edgelist = widths.keys(),
                       width=list(widths.values()),
                       edge_color='orange',
                       alpha=0.6)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos,
                        labels=d_labels,
                        font_color='white')
plt.box(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's nearly perfect! Last thing, is there a way to make it interactive? i.e. so I can change angles?

Comment: Not that I am aware of with networkx no.. . I have seen of node_picking (mentioned in the answer) but never tried it myself. Not the best tool nx for interactive plots @max

Comment: Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @MaxK, for interactive network graphs with networkx (+ Plotly and Dash), you should check this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-interactive-network-visualization-using-networkx-plotly-and-dash-e44749161ed7